# What statistical analysis? Three continuous independent variables w/ one categorical dependent

Tags: regression, survey

Trying to find what type of analysis to run. Im trying to determine if three continuous variables can predict a categorical dependent variable (physical activity) w/ three levels (high, medium, and low). Any ideas?

Comment: It’s called ordinal regression.

Comment: Welcome to cross validated, Mememex3!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordinal dependent variable with continuous independent variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52188/ordinal-dependent-variable-with-continuous-independent-variables)